# How to initialize a class' fields with a function in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there a way to initialize a field of a class with a function (where multiple steps would be required)?

Example: instead of:

```
class User {
  final String uid;
  final String fireBaseDisplayName;
  String shortenedName;

  User({
    this.uid,
    this.fireBaseDisplayName,
  }) : shortenedName =
            fireBaseDisplayName.substring(0, fireBaseDisplayName.indexOf(' '));
}
```

would this be possible:

```
  User({
    this.uid,
    this.fireBaseDisplayName,
  }) : shortenedName =
            shortenName(this.fireBaseDisplayName));
}

shortenName (fireBaseDisplayName) {
return fireBaseDisplayName.substring(0, fireBaseDisplayName.indexOf(' ');
};
```

Related [What is the difference between constructor and initializer list in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52013357/what-is-the-difference-between-constructor-and-initializer-list-in-dart)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can initialize fields with a function, but here's the catch: it has to be `static`. Either declare the function as `static` in your class or move it outside the class altogether. If the field isn't `final` (which for best practice, it should be, unless the field *has* to mutate), you can initialize it using a regular non-static method in the constructor body.

The reason final fields have to be initialized using a static function is because if the function was not static, it would have access to `this`. However, `this` is not available until all final fields have been initialized.

Comment: In case you use Dart >= 2.12 with null safety, the `String shortenedName;` field will give you an error because it's marked as an non null field(because it don't have the `?`), and you would need to add the `late` keyword to avoid the compiler `Non-nullable instance field 'shortenedName' must be initialized` error; like this: `late String shortenedName;`

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you want?

```
void main() {
  var user = User(id: "0", name: "Test user");
  print(user.name);
  print(user.firstName);
  print(user.lastName);
}

class User {
  final String id;
  final String name;
  String firstName, lastName;

  User({
    this.id,
    this.name,
  }) {
    initFirstName();
    initLastName();
  }

  initFirstName() {
    firstName = name.substring(0, name.indexOf(' '));
  }

  initLastName() {
    lastName = name.substring(name.indexOf(' ') + 1);
  }
}
```