# Dart - How to have class initializer functions work with constructors?

Tags: flutter, dart

Initializer functions are ignored if I create an instance through a constructor. How to have initializer functions work on constructors as well?
Here is how I call the class

```
User fireBaseUser = new User("12345","Test Name"); // shortenedName exists
var snap = {"uid" : "12345", "displayName" : "Test Name"};
User fireBaseUser = User.fromSnapshot(snap); // shortenedName wont exist

class User {
  final String uid;
  final String fireBaseDisplayName;
  String shortenedName;

  User.fromSnapshot( DocumentSnapshot document)
      : uid = snapshot.documentID,
        fireBaseDisplayName = snapshot['displayName'];

  User(
      {this.uid,
      this.fireBaseDisplayName,
      this.shortenedName,
     }) {
    shortenName(fireBaseDisplayName);
  }

  shortenName(fireBaseDisplayName) {
    shortenedName =
        fireBaseDisplayName.substring(0, fireBaseDisplayName.indexOf(' '));
  }
```

Constructor only seems to work if I duplicate the initializer funciton like this

```
class User {
  final String uid;
  final String fireBaseDisplayName;
  String shortenedName;

  User.fromSnapshot( DocumentSnapshot document)
      : uid = snapshot.documentID,
        fireBaseDisplayName = snapshot['displayName'];
        shortenedName = snapshot['displayName'].substring(0, snapshot['displayName'].indexOf(' '));

  User(
      {this.uid,
      this.fireBaseDisplayName,
      this.shortenedName,
     }) {
    shortenName(fireBaseDisplayName);
  }

  shortenName(fireBaseDisplayName) {
    shortenedName =
        fireBaseDisplayName.substring(0, fireBaseDisplayName.indexOf(' '));
  }
```

Related [How to initialize a class' fields with a function in dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62393610/how-to-initialize-a-class-fields-with-a-function-in-dart/62394306#62394306)

Comment: See https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#redirecting-constructors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a `generative constructor` :

```
User(
      {this.uid,
      this.fireBaseDisplayName,
      this.shortenedName,
     }) {
    shortenName(fireBaseDisplayName);
  }
```

and this is a `named constructor` :

```
User.fromSnapshot( DocumentSnapshot document)
      : uid = snapshot.documentID,
        fireBaseDisplayName = snapshot['displayName'];
```

in the object initialize `User fireBaseUser = User.fromSnapshot(snap);` you are calling the `named constructor` so you have to call the fun `shortenName(fireBaseDisplayName);` inside the `named constructor` you are calling, like this :

```
User.fromSnapshot( DocumentSnapshot document)
      : uid = snapshot.documentID, // snapshot or document?    :)
        fireBaseDisplayName = snapshot['displayName'] {
          shortenName(fireBaseDisplayName);
      }
```

Comment: see the docs     https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#constructors

Answer (score 0):

You used 'named parameter {}', so you should use parameter name.

1) shortenedName exists
User fireBaseUser = new User(uid: "12345",fireBaseDisplayName: "Test Name", shortenedName: "TN");

2) shortenedName not exists
User fireBaseUser = new User(uid: "12345",fireBaseDisplayName: "Test Name");

```
class User {
  final String uid;
  final String fireBaseDisplayName;
  String shortenedName;

  User({
      this.uid, 
      this.fireBaseDisplayName,
      this.shortenedName,
       });
```