# Firebase Instance with a variable in the "where" parameter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Starting in programming in flutter, i tried to create a simple view that returns firebase datas

I passed a value between 2 screens in the string "data" but when i try to add it to my firebase query, i got the following message :

> The instance member 'data' can't be accessed in an initializer.
> Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expressiondart(implicit_this_reference_in_initializer)

I don't get this error message when i replace it by a value between quotes :

Working :

```
      .where('Description', isEqualTo: 'ProductABC')
```

Not Working :

```
      .where('Description', isEqualTo: data)
```

Can you help me ?

Please find below the code line

```
class Itemscreen extends StatefulWidget {
  String data;
  Itemscreen({this.data});

  @override
  _ItemscreenState createState() => _ItemscreenState(data);
}

class _ItemscreenState extends State<Itemscreen> {
  String data;
  _ItemscreenState(this.data);
 
  FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _itemlist = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('ItemList')
      .where('Description', isEqualTo: data)
      .snapshots();
```

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message says, you can't use `data` (or any field) in the initialization block of an object.

You'll probably want to create it in the constructor/initializers, like this:

```
class _ItemscreenState extends State<Itemscreen> {
  String data;
  final FirebaseFirestore firestore
  final Stream<QuerySnapshot> itemlist
  _ItemscreenState(this.data): 
      firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance,
      _itemlist = FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('ItemList')
          .where('Description', isEqualTo: data)
          .snapshots();
```

Also see: [What is the difference between constructor and initializer list in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52013357/what-is-the-difference-between-constructor-and-initializer-list-in-dart)

Comment: Hi Franck !

Thanks for you precious help ! it works and now i see the difference between constructor and initializer.

Have a good day ;)

Answer (score 0):

add .trim() to variable data.trim()